# .NET stack overflow?

Tags: vb.net, performance, stack-overflow

In my VB.NET application, sometimes, I do heavy and deep iterations. Very long ones. It seems that, in some cases I get a stack overflow error, where apparently my application thinks I got an infinite loop or something, which I don't blame, I call a function quite a lot of times actually...

What should I do? This is a tile-based map editor, where I use the [flood fill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) algorithm (found in Wikipedia). If I use the flood fill tool on big maps, I get that error. But is there a way to tell the system to "just keep going dude, you'll get there" or something? I have seen other applications that can use flood fill on huge maps so I don't really want to disable/limit this feature in mine.

Comment: A stack overflow error usually means you have exceeded the capacity of a buffer.

Comment: So it is definitely a problem with the flood fill algorithm that should be possible to fix given other applications do it perfectly? Damn you Wikipedia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"just keep going dude, you'll get there" - You should just read the subsequent sections in the Wikipedia article.  The examples don't use recursion. =)